# Query with select and count in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I did this Query in SQL but I can't make it work in Eloquent.
Please help me.

```
SELECT 
    tags.desc,
    COUNT(planificacion_info.id_area) as cantidad_intervenciones
FROM 
    tags
    INNER JOIN planificacion_info ON planificacion_info.id_area = tags.id_tag
WHERE 
    tags.grupo = 'area' and tags.estado = true
GROUP BY
    tags.desc
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Tag::select(['tags.desc as area'], [Tag::raw('COUNT(planificacion_info.id_area) as cantidad_intervenciones')])->join('planificacion_info',  'planificacion_info.id_area', '=' , 'tags.id_tag')->where(['tags.grupo', '=' , 'area'], ['tags.estado', '=' , true])->groupBy('tags.desc');

But it finish on error in Grammar.php line 58: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
$result = \DB::table('tags')->selectRaw('tags.desc, COUNT(planificacion_info.id_area) as cantidad_intervenciones')
            ->join('planificacion_info', 'planificacion_info.id_area', '=', 'tags.id_tag')
            ->where('tags.grupo', 'area')
            ->whereRaw('tags.estado = true')
            ->groupBy('tags.desc')
            ->get();
```

which gives you this request :

```
SELECT 
  tags.desc, 
  COUNT(planificacion_info.id_area) AS cantidad_intervenciones 
FROM 
  `tags` 
  INNER JOIN `planificacion_info` ON `planificacion_info`.`id_area` = `tags`.`id_tag` 
WHERE 
  `tags`.`grupo` = 'area' 
  AND tags.estado = TRUE 
GROUP BY 
  `tags`.`desc`
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be something liek this

```
$tags= DB::table('tags')
    ->select('tags.desc',DB::raw("COUNT(planificacion_info.id_area) AS cantidad_intervenciones")
    ->innerJoin('planificacion_info','planificacion_info.id_area','=','tags.id_tag')
    ->where('tags.grupo','area')
    ->where('tags.estado',true)
    ->groupBy('tags.desc')
    ->get();
```